Fixing "Font shape `T3/lmr/m/n' undefined" for tipa symbol
What does the warning
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T3/lmr/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T3/cmr/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textteshlig' on input line 273.

mean? And what can I do to fix it?
I am using
\RequirePackage[T2A,LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[safe]{tipa}


EDIT:
The following output is what I get when running egreg's code:
*****
*****     PDFLaTeX output: 
*****     cd "~/test fonts"
*****     pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode test.tex
*****
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2aenc.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t2aenc.dfu))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-fontenc/lgrenc.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-inputenc/lgrenc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-fontenc/greek-fontenc.def))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/tipa.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/t1lmss.fd))))
No file T3lmr.fd.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
No file test.aux.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmr.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cbfonts-fd/lgrcmr.fd) [1{/var/lib/texm
f/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux) ){/usr/share/texmf/fonts/en
c/dvips/lm/lm-ec.enc}</usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr10.pfb></usr/sh
are/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipa10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 29767 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
*****
*****     PDFLaTeX output: 
*****     cd "~/test fonts"
*****     pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode test.tex
*****
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2aenc.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t2aenc.dfu))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-fontenc/lgrenc.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-inputenc/lgrenc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-fontenc/greek-fontenc.def))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/tipa.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/t1lmss.fd))))
No file T3lmr.fd.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./test.aux) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmr.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cbfonts-fd/lgrcmr.fd) [1{/var/lib/texm
f/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux) ){/usr/share/texmf/fonts/en
c/dvips/lm/lm-ec.enc}</usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr10.pfb></usr/sh
are/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipa10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 29767 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
*****
*****     PDFLaTeX output: 
*****     cd "~/test fonts"
*****     pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode test.tex
*****
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2aenc.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t2aenc.dfu))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-fontenc/lgrenc.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-inputenc/lgrenc.dfu)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-fontenc/greek-fontenc.def))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/tipa.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/lm/t1lmss.fd))))
No file T3lmr.fd.
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./test.aux) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyrillic/t2acmr.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cbfonts-fd/lgrcmr.fd) [1{/var/lib/texm
f/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux) ){/usr/share/texmf/fonts/en
c/dvips/lm/lm-ec.enc}</usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr10.pfb></usr/sh
are/texmf/fonts/type1/fkr/tipa/tipa10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 29767 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.


please always provide an example that shows the problem, not just fragments. \documentclass{article} \RequirePackage[T2A,LGR,T1]{fontenc} \RequirePackage[safe]{tipa} \begin{document} x\textteshlig y \end{document}  runs without any warning in texlive 2024

oh lmr.........

TeX Live 2019? That's five years behind.

@egreg: As I mentioned: I have a pretty old Kubuntu version and are not able to switch the OS right now - that is why my LaTeX is rather old. (I am not sure how to update LaTeX independently from the OS.)

@Make42 See https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-1/tb100gregorio.pdf or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu/95373#95373

You did not provide a full example but
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\RequirePackage[T2A,LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[safe]{tipa}
\begin{document}
x\textteshlig y
\end{document}

Produces the warning shown. It just means the TIPA symbol is not available in a latin modern based T3 encoded font and the Computer Modern one will be used. As Latin Modern and Computer Modern are essentially the same design this warning isn't really reporting any serious issue.

Latin Modern doesn't support IPA (that is, T3 encoding). Replace with Computer Modern.
The substitution is made anyway, but using \DeclareFontFamilySubstitution removes the warning.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T2A,LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[safe]{tipa}

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T3}{\familydefault}{cmr}

\begin{document}

x\textteshlig y

explanation \textipa{[""Ekspl@"neIS@n]}

\end{document}



Adding \DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T3}{\familydefault}{cmr} to the preamble causes the error "LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T3/lmr/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using T3/cmr/m/n instead
(Font)              for symbol textteshlig on input line 273.
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
@spaces ->space
space space space
l.273 ...ycounter[]{page}\glsnumberformat{xxxii}}}
\glsgroupskip"

I replaced \textteshlig with a and I did not get an error, even when having \DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T3}{\familydefault}{cmr} in the preamble. Once I replace the a back to \textteshlig, I get the "capacity exceeded" error again.

I had the idea now to use \DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T3}{lmr}{cmr} instead. That seems to work. Is this legit?

But I still get the warning "No file t3lmr.fd" - is this connected or a different issue (and thus a different question at stackexchange)?

@Make42 I get no warning from the code I posted.

I posted the entire output (which I get from your MWE) in my question. I a pretty old Kubuntu version and are not able to switch the OS right now - that is why my LaTeX is rather old. (I am not sure how to update LaTeX independently from the OS.)

@Make42 That's not a warning. If you don't want to see it, create an empty t3lmr.fd file in the working directory.


If it is not a warning: is it just information? 2. Is using \DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{T3}{lmr}{cmr} a legit way for me (as long as I stick with latin modern for T3) or might that produce issues which I am not aware of?


@Make42 1. Information. 2. No.

:-D You answered "No" to an "or" question. I do not know to which part you say "no".
